# Several JSON for one page rendered by Dust.js

Tags: javascript, json, dust.js

I wonder if I can use several JSONs when I'm rendering a page with dust.js.

For example, I am on the client side.
I download my JSONs (JSON1 and JSON2) and my dust template (dustTemplate). I compile and load my template. After I would render my page with the 2 JSONs.

For now I do :`dust.render("template" , JSON, function(err, out) {...});`
But it uses one JSON, is there a way to use 2 or more JSONs ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use 2 JSON or more for rendering one page. We can merge the JSONs with jQuery

```
var jsonMerge = $.extend({}, JSON1, JSON2);
var templateCompiled = dust.compile(dustTemplate, "template");
dust.loadSource(templateCompiled );
dust.render("template" , jsonMerge , function(err, out) {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use multiple JSON payloads on a single page (and they don't need to arrive at the same time). Each payload needs its own call to `dust.render`, though they can potentially use the same template, if you want.

For instance:

```
async('GET', url1, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    dust.render('template1', data, function(err, out) {
      if (typeof out === 'string') {
        container1.innerHTML = out;
      }
    });
  }
});

async('GET', url2, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    dust.render('template2', data, function(err, out) {
      if (typeof out === 'string') {
        container2.innerHTML = out;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. But actually I wanted to use 2 JSON or more for one page. I found I can merge the JSON like this with jQuery : var jsonMerge = $.extend({}, JSON1, JSON2);
But your solution works great for rendering two pages or more :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution pointed by @Mitch simple and efficient. Other way to do this without using jquery is http://jsfiddle.net/yXx5L/4/

Using `dust.makeBase` to aggregate the jsons of the page to a single context stack, upon which dust can look for the keys.